# Inside a Windows Store 8.1 app can i share a link to a web address which allows a user to download a .exe file?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, packaging

My requirement is to associate a .exe file with a Windows Store 8.1 app. Is it acceptable to give a link through about section of the store app to a web address from where the user can download the .exe file. Will there be any problem with the certification process. Please suggest any suitable alternative if possible.

Comment: You should try it. But if the app is only to download the .exe it might not pass certification. Also in certification process the category of app have big impact. I have a Tool app and it takes 30 minutes to release. Other apps like games or video takes more than a day.
Write a good policy and when the user clicks the link add a MessegeDialog and say something like "By clicking this link you will be redirected blabla... are you sure?"

Comment: What are you trying to do with the exe?

Comment: @Stamos, thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in the [Windows Store Policies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/dn764944.aspx) that says otherwise. You can't attempt to run the *.exe file programmatically of course, but you should be fine otherwise.

Since the app is network-capable, remember to add a Privacy Policy (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280292/where-in-windows-8-app-should-you-code-privacy-policy)) detailing whether any user information is sent to an external website/server.